# Showing $∇$ x $\left(f^2∇f\right)=0$

Tags: vector-fields, scalar-fields

I am trying to show that $∇$ x $\left(f^2∇f\right)=0$ (the zero vector)

I know that from the expansion we get $∇f^2$ x $∇f\:+\:f^2∇$ x $∇f$
From this we can say that $f^2∇$ x $∇f$ = 0 as the curve of a gradient is 0.
That leaves me with $∇f^2$ x $∇f$. How do i show that this is also equal to 0?

Comment: Could you use Latex notation for your formulas ?

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Note that $\nabla f^2 = 2f\nabla f$ and use what you know about $X\times X$. You can also note that $f^2\nabla f = \frac{1}{3}\nabla f^3$ in the original expression.

Comment: @Winther so therefore i would have 2f∇f x ∇f. How does that then equal 0?

Comment: When is the cross-product zero? It might help to add some brackets $(\ldots)$ and put the scalar $2f$ outside the bracket.

Comment: when two vectors have the same direction? @Winther

Comment: And do they have the same direction?

Comment: @Winther yes became they are the same vector?

Comment: Exactly. $a\vec{X}$ and $\vec{X}$ point in the same direction and this is the case here with $a=2f$ and $\vec{X} = \vec{\nabla} f$